# How to sum numbers in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im trying to sum the total result of each row and column in a 3x4 matrix but the problem is that because in Javascript the type of a variable depends on the value I can't order the operation to treat the values as integers. This is the code:

```
 let Fila, Columna, Matriz=[[],[],[]], Vector1=[0,0,0,0],Vector2=[],cadena;

for(Fila=0;Fila<3;Fila++){
    for(Columna=0;Columna<4;Columna++){

        Matriz[Fila][Columna] = parseInt(prompt('DIGITAR NUMERO DE LA FILA '+(Fila+1)+' COLUMNA '+(Columna+1)));
        Vector1[Columna] += parseInt(Matriz[Fila][Columna]);
        
    }
        Vector2[Fila] = Matriz[Fila].reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
        
}
```

Vector2 does the operation correctly, but unless I declare each position in Vector1 at the start as a number the result is NaN. Is there a workaround for this? How do I specify that I want an undefined array to realize math operations with the values asigned to it?

Answer (score 0):

If you initialise `Vector1` as an empty array, then the `+=` operator will look for a value in the array which is not there, and so the sum is not a number.

You can avoid this by detecting that the array element does not exist yet, and using the value 0 instead as the operand for the sum:

```
Vector1[Columna] = (Vector1[Columna] ?? 0) + parseInt(Matriz[Fila][Columna]);
```

Unrelated, but in JavaScript it is common practice to start variable names with a lowercase letter, and reserve the first capital for names of classes/constructors. So name your variables `vector1`, `columna`, `fila`,...

Answer (score 0):

If you try to use the `+=` operator on a variable that has not been assigned a value, JavaScript will treat the variable as having an initial value of `undefined`. This operation would result in a value of `NaN` (Not a Number) because you cannot perform addition with undefined.

Here's an example:

```js
let undefinedVariable;
undefinedVariable += 5;

console.log(undefinedVariable); // Output: NaN
```

In this example, `undefinedVariable` is not assigned a value explicitly, so its initial value is `undefined`. When you attempt to use `+=` on it, JavaScript treats `undefinedVariable` as `NaN` in the addition operation, resulting in `NaN`.

If you don't want to initialize each position, you can always check if the value for `Vector1[Columna]` is undefined to know if you perform a `+=` or `=` set operation.

And that's also why this line works `Vector2[Fila] = Matriz[Fila].reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)`

Even though you have not initialized `Vector2`, it is able to work because you are using a `=` set operation.

Hope it helped!